# Combining caps text and italics

Tags: fonts

I've been editing a LaTeX template for my thesis.
The title page looks like this :

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\bgroup
\scshape{\LARGE title of the document} \\
\egroup
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

One of the words in the title for my paper needs to be italicized. I've tried

```
\scshape{\LARGE title of the document \textit{italicized word}} \\
```

But then the other formatting doesn't apply to the italics.
How do I add the italicized word in while keeping the other formating?

Comment: Hi Amanda and welcome to TeX.SE! It is very likely, that there are no small caps available in italic shape, as this is a combination that is not used very often. Where does this requirement to set italic small caps come from?

Comment: One is a thesis requirement and the other is because the word is a Genus and species name and should be italicized by convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to employ a font that features the smallcaps/italic combination font dimensions. One such font is Times (New) Roman.

[image]

Incidentally, `\scshape` -- like `\LARGE` -- does not take an argument. To limit the scope of `\scshape`, write either `{\scshape ...}` or, perhaps more directly, `\textsc{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % or some other Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\scshape\LARGE title of the document \textit{italicized word} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another font package that provides the smallcaps/italic combination is `newpxtext`. This font is clone of Palatino.

Comment: I added a more comprehensive list to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the Latex New Font Selection Scheme traditionally had only two font parameters: the series and the shape.  Both of these combined multiple font features, so a series might be bold extended or semibold condensed, and a shape might be italic, small caps, upright italic or italic small caps.

There are three solutions.

#### Use Fontspec

In the modern toolchain, with LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can load `fontspec`.  This has a few traces of the NFSS family/series/shape system remaining in its interface, but if will activate the OpenType Small Caps feature of the Italic font.  Or, if there is a separate font for it, you specify that with:

```
\setmainfont{SomeFont}[
  ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont =
                    {SomeFont-RegularItalicSC.ttf}}]
```

#### Use Fontaxes

With legacy 8-bit fonts, the solution is `fontaxes`, which divides the shape axis into a primary shape axis (normal, italic, slanted, etc.) and a secondary shape axis (small caps).  This lets you write `\textit{\textsc{Foo}}` or `{\itshape\scshape\selectfont Foo}`

The other solutions that say to load a particular font package work because many newer font packages load `fontaxes`.  Note that, if you had been relying on `\itshape` or `\scshape` to reset each other, you might need to specify `\upshape` or `\ulcshape` to turn italics or small caps off, respectively.

#### Load the Italic Small Caps Face

As a last resort, it is possible to specify this font series without `fontaxes`.  It is usually, but not always, `scit`.

So, if you want TeX Gyre Pagella, whose family name is `qpl`,¹ looking up `t1qpl.fd` shows that `\fontfamily{qpl}\fontshape{scit}\selectfont` will work, and `scsl` is also supported as an alias for `scit`.  The font file this actually loads is named `ec-qplri-sc.tfm`, if you ever need to load it in plain TeX.

¹ If you care, this is because it was originally called Quasi-Palatino until GUST changed the name for legal reasons.  It was meant as a drop-in replacement for the standard PostScript font Palatino, `ppl`.  All the older family, series and shape names are so terse because they needed to fit inside the 8 characters MS-DOS allowed for a file name.  New fonts that never needed to support older OSes usually have a family name like `DejaVuSerif-TLF`.

#### PS

Most OpenType fonts contain Italic small caps.  The following 8-bit fonts declare a `{m}{scit}` version in a `*.fd` file and will work with the `fontaxes` commands above:

The TeX Gyre fonts (`qag`, `qbk`, `qcs`, `qhv`, `qhvc`, `qpl`, `qtm`) and their X forks (TeX Gyre Schola X, etc.), Roboto,  Antykwa Toruńska, Erewhon, `ETbb`, `zpl`, Go, XCharter, `fbb`, Cochineal, Gentium, Cabin, Cyclop, NewTX, Kurier, Alegreya, Iwona, Raleway, Junicode, Baskerville, GaramondLibre, IbarraRealNova, Old Standard, Montserrat, `zcsth`, Libertinus, :inux Libertine/Biolinum, SticksToo, Fira Sans, `hfor`, `hfoss`, Playfair, BaskervaldX, EB Garamond, Coelacanth, Noto Sans/Serif, and many, many variants of Computer Modern.

Nearly all fonts that support `scit` also alias it to `scsl`.  A few only support `scsl`, including the KP fonts and `clm2`.  You would need to use `\slshape\scshape\selectfont` or `\textsl{\textsc{...}}` with them.  A few have distinct italic and slanted small caps.

A handful of others call this series `itsc` instead, such as `cm-lgc`.  These might need a new `\DeclareFontShape` definition, or a `\fontshape{itsc}\selectfont` command.